# Abrindo página via AJAX com Lightbox

Tags: jquery, ajax

Eu estou usando AJAX e Lightbox pra carregar uma página. Não irei postar o código todo mas o link que eu uso para ativar o Lightbox e carregar a página AJAX é ativado assim:

```
<a class="lightbox" href="#" onclick="abrirPag('editandomi.php?I_POST=<?php echo $posts['ID'] ?>');">
    TEXTO OU IMAGEM QUE TERÁ O LINK    
</div>
```

A pagina `editandomi.php` capta por meio `GET` o `id` daquele conteúdo e exibe informações detalhadas, **porém** eu quero melhorar isso... Quero fazer tipo no Facebook, quando se clica em cima de uma imagem ou video, se abre um Lightbox e a URL muda para de:

```
https://www.facebook.com/
```

Para algo do tipo:

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=516159178490002&set=a.409523075820280.1073741826.100002877744748&type=1&theater
```

e ao clicar para fechar esse Lightbox a URL volta novamente para

```
https://www.facebook.com/
```

**Como fazer esse tipo de carregamento via AJAX?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para isto, você precisa da API de histórico do HTML5:

```
history.pushState( estado, titulo, url );
```

Como você só postou o código principal, não tenho como por detalhes no momento, mas para o efeito desejado, o essencial é acrescentar o `pushState` na sua função `abrirPag`:

```
history.pushState( null, null, parametroUsadoNoAbrirPag );
```

Para fazer um código mais completo e uma melhor experiência para o usuário, você pode implementar o `popstate` ao abrir o *lightbox*, para que a tecla backspace ou o botão de "voltar" do navegador funcione corretamente, tanto fechando o lightbox quanto mostrando a foto anterior, dependendo da sua implementação:

```
window.addEventListener( "popstate", function(e) {
   // Aqui vai o código para voltar ao estado anterior da navegacao
});
```

O primeiro parametro do pushState mencionado anteriormente (estado), serve justamente para guardar os dados que você quiser, para poder usar na função acima. Se preferir, pode processar a URL diretamente, e não usar o estado/state.

> Eis um belo tutorial neste link: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html <sup>(en)</sup>

**[Aqui](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/fer.html)**, um demo de uma galeria de fotos em ajax, com histórico, e seu respectivo **[source](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/gallery.js)**.
Notar que nos browsers mais velhos, os URLs funcionam perfeitamente, mesmo sem Ajax.

Comment: Sua resposta foi exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Inclusive o demo que você me passo, já que eu pretendo fazer uma galeria.

Comment: @ivanveloso gostei bastante da simplicidade daquele demo, e o tutorial do pessoal lá é bem explicadinho. No seu caso específico, acho que o único acrescimo vai ser abrir o lightbox automaticamente quando a URL tiver o parâmetro da foto (caso o usuário copie o link da foto aberta). Sucesso na implementação!