# Mudar de página sem alterar a URL do usuário

Tags: javascript, c#

Como trocar de páginas internamente sem alterar a URL pro usuário? **Sem utilizar frames.**

Exemplo:
O usuário entrou no meu site: `http://exemplo.com` e clicou no menu e foi pra página "Contato".

Fazer com que a URL continue: `http://exemplo.com`, mesmo a página atual sendo `http://exemplo.com/contato.html`

Comment: Com estas especificações que você deu apenas com ajax

Comment: Você pode até simular isso com a api de _history_, mas provavelmente terá em algum momento efeitos colaterais indesejados. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16799/70

Comment: Já tentou usar [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/guides/) ? Pode ser útil!

Comment: Como apontado pelo @ErlonCharles, está parecendo mesmo que Ajax é o caso, se não houver preocupação com histórico (para o usuário) e SEO; afinal, não queremos voltar à era do Flash, né! Hahaha!

Você poderia dar uma olhada em AngularJS. Acredito que ele possui duas características úteis nesse caso: templates e routing.

Comment: Outro _reparo técnico_ (1): é usar POST. Assim você teria botões no lugar de links, e na index processaria o valor do POST para definir o conteúdo. Essa funciona mesmo com JS desligado. _1. Gambiarra_

Comment: NULL conseguiste resolver o problema?

Comment: Um amigo meu falou que conseguiu achar a solução usando URL Rewrite, vou verificar com ele.

Comment: Então seria bom se você postasse a solução aqui, se ela funcionar mesmo. Mas... URL Rewrite? Tem certeza?

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo carregar a página que vc quer dentro de uma `div`

```
<div id='conteudo'>
```

E um botão para disparar o evento de carga :

```
<div id='newConteudo'>
```

Com a ajuda do jquery:

```
$('#newConteudo').on('click', function(){
    $('#conteudo').load('subPag.php')
});
```

neste caso o arquivo `subPag.php` terá a função montar a nova subPágina considerando que o assunto carregado fará parte de uma página principal que não será recarregada.

O arquivo `subPag.php` deverá ser tratado como um trecho de página mesmo. Não deverá ter as tags `<head>` ou `<body>`, é um trecho da sua página original.

Isto tem suas vantagens:

- O CSS da página original afeta a subpágina,
- As funções javascript/jquery a pagina original também podem funcionar na subpágina, contanto que tenha utilizado `.on`.

Não recomendo carregar muito script na subpágina, pois vai carregando a página principal e facilmente pode gerar conflitos.

Existe ainda outra possibilidade com a carga via `$.post`. Nesta opção você utiliza de um botão/link para ativar a função, que por sua vez pode enviar alguns dados ou até campos de formulários a um arquivo PHP. este arquivo PHP, por sua vez, processa os dados e retribui via JSON um conjunto de informações. Estas informações podem ser processadas na função de retorno do comando `$.post` e direcionadas para uma div ou outro local/elemento da página para alteração da página atual. Isto tudo sem alterar a URL do topo da página.

Comment: Olá @SULBACH, seja bem vindo ao SOPT, editei sua pergunta para adicionar a marcação de amostras de código, que facilita a leitura da resposta. Para mais informações visite a central de ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

Talvez você queira trabalhar com a troca de links que se a página sofra um reload.. Entendi certo?

O mais aconselhado para esses casos é trabalhar com [Deep Linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking)

Uma ótima biblioteca para trabalhar com o Deep Linking em `JS` é a [`SwfAddress` da Asual](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/)

Você navega entre páginas através de `Ajax` sem que sua página sofra um reload e ainda coloca um histórico de navegação em sua url que passa a ser trabalhada da seguinte forma:

> www.site.com.br
>
> www.site.com.br/#/contato

sendo que em `/#/contato` a chamada seria ao seu arquivo `contato.html`

veja um exemplo dessa navegação [aqui](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/samples/ajax/)

Comment: Minha dúvida é não mostrar da "/" pra frente, o usuário só vai ver: site.com/

Comment: Nesse caso... Esqueça Deep Linking, histórico, Angular Routing e qualquer outra coisa. Se você não quer MESMO tocar na URL, utilize Ajax puro ou então o "reparo técnico" sugerido pelo @Bacco nos comentários da sua pergunta. Mas voltamos a provocar a discussão: precisa MESMO manter esse URL estático? Páginas simples geralmente não justificam uso do AJAX, pela complexidade adicional, problemas com Search Engine Optimization e o já citado histórico/favorito do usuário. Uma coisa é não indexar os resultados de uma query ou outro conteúdo dinâmico, mas dados estáticos (aos olhos do usuário)?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira de se fazer isso é utilizando o history.js

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

É robusto e simples de implementar. Basta fazer o download, adiciona-lo à sua solution e então consumi-lo numa function javascript.

Segue um exemplo funcional de como mudar a URL do seu site após o usuário clicar em algum botão do menu Contato:

> HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste de mudança de URL</title>  
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="btnAdd">exemplo 1</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="btnRem">exemplo 2</button>                
        </li>                
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</body>
```

> Javascript - neste caso, carregado no final do código HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.history.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnAdd').click(function(){ 
        History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1");
    });
    $('#btnRem').click(function(){ 
        History.replaceState({state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2&user=beto");       
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Em javascript nativo da para fazer assim:

`<script> 
     document.getElementById("id_da_div_ou_Body").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="arquivo.php" ></object>'; 
</script>`